# Unable to play(using AudioTrack) Captured PCM audio using Visualizer

Tags: android, media-player, visualizer, audiotrack

I m trying to capture the played file in MediaPlayer using Visualizer and play it using AudioTrack. But the captured data is noise only.

Here is my code.

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.call_ringtone);
                mPlayer.setLooping(false);
                mPlayer.start();
               // mPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
                int minSize =AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize( 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT );        
                 mySong = new AudioTrack( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
                mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);

            Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener()
            {
                Boolean toPlay = false;
                @Override
                public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                        int samplingRate)
                {
                     myl.add(bytes);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                        int samplingRate)
                {
                    System.out.println("onFftDataCapture");
                }
            };

            mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener,
                    Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);

            mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
                {
                    mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
                    stopIt = true;
                }
            });


            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(30000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mySong.play();
                    int j=0;
                    while(j<myl.size())
                    {
                    mySong.write(myl.get(j), 0, myl.get(j).length);
                    Log.d("writing", Integer.toString(j)+" : "+Integer.toString(temp.length));
                    j++;
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

bytes are just generating raw white noise. How can is the data coming in OnWaveForm method have format PCM? how can i get from that?

Comment: Were u successful in doing this ? If yes can you please post the code ? Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using soundpool instead of audiotrack